How to centre the data in a currency column that does not remove the £ or decimal
I'm trying to centre the data in my SharePoint List's currency columns (Unit Price, Origination and Delivery Cost). I found an answer that supplied some JSON code to add, which worked but changed my decimal places from 0.00 to 0.0 - is there an additional piece of code I need to prevent this from happening?
Here is the code I'm currently using:
{

"$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
"elmType": "div",
"txtContent": "='£' + '@currentField'",
"style": {
"display": "flex",
"justify-content": "center",
"align-items": "center"
}
}

I have no code experience, so I am totally out of my comfort zone!
Any help will greatly appreciated!

For your txtContent, I would try '@currentField.displayValue'
Syntax reference here
{

  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField.displayValue",
  "style": {
     "display": "flex",
     "justify-content": "center",
     "align-items": "center"
   }
}


Thank you - Although this added an extra £ sign. Could you please provide the whole code?

@KayleeBiddle if you are getting an extra £ you could try removing from your json. sample added above

Thank you! That worked a treat! :)

Paul Lucas is right, we usually use @currentField to get the value of a column so that you don't lose the accuracy of the data.
Please try use this JSON:
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "text-align": "center"
  },
  "txtContent": "@currentField"
}

